# How can I save the content of an xml file that's in a blob container to a variable in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm able to get the xml content from the blob in a web activity and store it in a variable. However, the variable is set to JSON notation with the following format:

`{

"name": "",

"value": ""

}`

I need to send the xml content through an API, but can't access the xml content from the value property of the variable.

I've tried using the xml() function to convert but it's not working.

Comment: You can use expression `@variables('<variable-name>')`  to access the xml data of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"name": "",
"value": ""
}
```

This is the output of set variable activity. Name property will have name of the variable and value will have value of the variable. In this case, value will have the XML response of web activity. If you want to access the value of the variable, you can use `@variables('<variable-name>')` in the expression.

I tried to repro this with sample value.

- Web activity is taken and output of the web activity is as follows.
  [image]
- The response is stored in a variable of string type.
  [image]
- Output of Set variable activity:

[image]

- Value of variable v1 is assigned to variable v2 expresssion is given as `@variable(v1)`

[image]